# Reshaping an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to reshape `I1` from `(7,2)` to `(1,7,2)` by means of a variable `k` which has the shape of old `I1`. But I get an error. Is there a way to do it?

```
import numpy as np

I1= np.array([[0, 1],
              [0, 2],
              [1, 3],
              [2, 3],
              [2, 5],
              [3, 6],
              [5, 6]])
k=I1.shape
I1=I1.reshape(1,k)
```

The error is

```
<module>
    I1=I1.reshape(1,k)

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: you don't want to reshape, you want to add dim, try this : `I1[None,...]`

Comment: Best way to do this is, as say @I'mahdi adding a new dimension `I1[None,:,:]` will give you a new array with an aditional axis with length 1. It's the same as  `I1[np.newaxis,:,:]` (new axis it's actually `None` but in a pretty way to be clear that you are adding an axis). Last but less recommendable is to create a list with `I1` and then  create array agayn (more computation, less pretty, slower but a posible way) `np.array( [I1] )`

Comment: `(1,k)` as a tuple is `(1, (7,2))`.  It should be (1,7,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because k is a tuple with 2 elements, when it's passed to a function, an asterisk `*` is needed.

Instead of `I1 = I1.reshape(1, k)`, try `I1 = I1.reshape(1, *k)`